# JQuery slidedown a div with a image is not smooth

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making a naviget menu like IBM's website, when mouse hover it will slidedown a pannel. I use jQuery's slidedown, and it seems work well but when you fisrt slidedown it, it will stuck for a moment like this.

[image: it stuck]

And after about 0.2 second，it continue to slidedown, this time works will.

[image: this is the right part after slidedown]

Confusely if you redo the above opreate immediately, it slidedown smoothly and not stuck. And after one minute or refrash the website it stuck again.

I check this problem for two day, and I found this may cause by the image which need some time to load, beacuse when I remove the image it works well. But I don't know how to fix it, i'm already add overflow: hidden in all parents div, even use transition to replace the jQuery slidedown but it stuck too. What's more I can't rewrite the code of this part beacuse it's written by other person and I don't really know what have he down.

There are some codes I wrote or I know how it works:

HTML:

```
<div class="nav-item-con clearfix <#if 1!=field.index>none</#if>">
```

Javascript:

```
if($(this).parent().index() === current) {
    if(!expanded) {
        expanded = true;
        $(this).stop().slideDown(250);
    }
    else {
        $('.nav-item').css('display', 'none');
        $(this).css('display', 'block');
    }
}
```

CSS:

```
#header-box .nav .nav-item {
    position: absolute; top: 3.5rem; right: 0; left: 0;
    /*background: #20273C;*/
    display: none;
    background: rgba(32,39,60,0.8);
```

I'm appreciate if you know how to solve this problem.

Comment: can you provide a snippet or the location? We may figure it out if we can really see the problem.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?